# Convergence in probability of symmetric random variable using characteristic function

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

> Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be independent, symmetric random variables with characteristic functions $\varphi_{1},\varphi_{2},\dots$
>
> **Prove:**
>
> If $\varphi_{1},\varphi_{2},\dots$ is differentiable at zero, then $\frac{X_1+\dots +X_n}{n}$ converges in probability to zero.

---

My attempt:

Use the Weak Law of Large Numbers for not identical distributed variables. For this I need

- the mean of  $X_i$ is zero,
- independence of the $X_i$,
- finite variance.

The mean is zero, because the variables are symmetric. The independence also is given. I conclude the finite variance should be shown by the differentiability of $\varphi_n$. For the derivatives it holds that
$$
\varphi_n^{(k)}(t)=i^k\mathbb E\left(X_n^ke^{itX_n}\right)
$$
so I know that 
$$
\varphi_n^{(1)}(0)=i\mathbb E(X_n)
$$ 
exists for any $n = 1,2,\dots$. But I don't get the information about the variance or the second moment.

Hints? Thoughts?

Comment: What is $\varphi$?

Comment: $\varphi$ is the characteristic function. So the precondition is that all characteristic functions of $X_1$,... are differentiable at $0$.

Comment: The characteristic function of what? I mean, $\varphi_{1}$ is the  characteristic function of $X_1$, $\varphi_{2}$ is the  characteristic function of $X_2$, etc. But $\varphi$ is the   characteristic function of nothing.

Comment: Be careful.  Having a symmetric distribution implies that *if the mean exists* it must be 0.  There are symmetric distributions with no mean, such as the [standard Cauchy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution).  And you are going to have to do without the condition of finite variance; it won't follow from the conditions you have.

Comment: I hope I fixed the notation with $\varphi_n$ - please take a look if it is what you wanted to say.

Comment: So I can't conlude $E(X_n)=0$ directly from the symmetry. But I can conlude it then from $E(X_n)=i^{-1}\varphi^{(1)}_n(0)$ and the symmetry, can I? Because $|\varphi^{(1)}_n(0)|<\infty$.

Comment: Yes, but you should look carefully at your proof that $E(X_n)=i^{−1} \varphi^{(1)}_n(0)$ to make sure that it doesn't *assume* that $E(X_n)$ exists.

Comment: Hmmm... Is this result true? Assume $X_n=a_nY_n$ for your favorite sequence $(a_n)$ of real numbers with $a_n\to\infty$ extremely fast, and your favorite sequence $(Y_n)$ of i.i.d. well behaved random variables, say Bernoulli or gaussian.

Comment: Hmmm (bis)... I just checked the previous version(s) of the question and it seems that some later interventions might have modified the text too drastically: are you in fact assuming that the random variables $X_n$ are i.i.d.?

Comment: No, I'm just assuming independence and symmetry.

Comment: Were there interventions putting forward an i.i.d. condition?

Comment: I found a paper considering the relation of the mean and the derivative of the characteristic function: http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.aoms/1177730443 ...But there should be a more simple solution to the problem.

Comment: *No, I'm just assuming independence and symmetry*... Then the result does not hold, for the reason previously explained. (Unrelated: please use @ to signal comments.)

Answer (score 1):

If the only assumptions are independence and symmetry, the result is not true. For a counterexample, assume $X_n=a_nY_n$ for your favorite sequence $(a_n)$ of real numbers such that $a_n\to\infty$ quickly, and your favorite sequence $(Y_n)$ of i.i.d. well behaved random variables, say centered Bernoulli or standard normal.

Comment: To sum up, the Edit history of the question shows that a perfectly valid question (every i.i.d. sequence with a hypothesis on their common characteristic function satisfies a weak law of large numbers) was, later on, transformed into an incorrect statement: Edit #2 cancels the equidistribution hypothesis, without which the result does not hold. The OP might have been interested in restoring the original (correct) version of the question but this never happened.